# bioinformatics code: l have this code and l want the input to be two strings: Text and pattern and the output to be a number

Tags: python, bioinformatics

```
def PatternCount(Text,Pattern):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,len(Text)-len(Pattern)):
        if Text[i:len(Pattern)] == Pattern:
            count = count + 1
    return count
Text = input("enter DNA string")
Pattern = input("enter 1st Pattern")
```

this is my code.

- Input: Strings Text and Pattern.
- Output: Count(Text, Pattern).

For example:

- Sample Input:

  - Text: GCGCG
  - Pattern: GCG
- Sample Output:

  - 2

Answer (score 1):

The second number in `Text[i:len(Pattern)]` is not length but final position. You need to add `i` to it.

Also, to find the final match, you need to iterate one more cycles.

```
def PatternCount(Text,Pattern):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, 1 + len(Text) - len(Pattern)):
        if Text[i:i + len(Pattern)] == Pattern:
            count = count + 1
    return count
Text = input("enter DNA string ")
Pattern = input("enter 1st Pattern ")
print(PatternCount(Text,Pattern))
```

Comment: ok if l want to read file and sort its contents into text and pattern, instead of the user input How can l do that? the file is text file and has two lines: one is a long DNA string and the other line is a specific pattern

Comment: Start a new question to ask a new question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to a corrected function as shown by choroba, you could use [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) -

```
import re
print(len(list(re.finditer("(?=%s)" % Pattern, Text))))
```

- or as well [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) with the same zero-width look-ahead pattern.